# Simple query not running

Tags: php, mysql

First off, I am aware I am open to SQL injection, this is just a prototype.  But it still should be working.

For the life of me I can't figure out why I can't pull an item out of my array.  What could I possibly be doing wrong?  I've been fiddling with this seemingly simple query for way too long and I can't seem to get it to pull out data.  I feel like it is something so simple....

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "' . $email . '"';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$ID = $row['ID'];
```

I am getting no result for $ID ....

Here is my entire code:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php

$email = $_GET["email"];
$servername="localhost";
$username="*****";
$password="*****";
$database="*****";
$conn= mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$database",$conn);


$query = 'SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = "' . $email . '"';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());



//Checks if the email address exists in the system already
if (mysql_num_rows($result) ) {
        die("Duplicate email found!");
    }
    else {
          //use current date/time combination times the number 11 times the ID to get a unique confirmation number.
          $query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "' . $email . '"';
          $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
          $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
          $ID = $row['ID'];
          echo $row;
          $date = date("mydhis");
          $date2 = $date * 11 * $ID;
          echo $ID . "  <-> " . $date . "  <->  <p>" . $date2;
          $sql="insert into users (first,last,displayname,email,password,verification_email)values('$_GET[first]','$_GET[last]','$_GET[display]','$_GET[email]','$_GET[password]','$date2')";
          $result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or $string = mysql_error();
          $confirmlink = "http://www.somewebsite.com/android/confirm.php?" . $date2;


          $to = $_GET['email'];
          $subject = "Thank you for Registering!";
          $message = "Hello " . $_GET['display'] . " and thank you for registering with the Smeet app!  To confirm your email address (and let us know you aren't a bot), please click the following link: " . $confirmlink;
          $from = "noreply@smeet.com";
          $headers = "From:" . $from;
          mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) or die('You have successfully registered however mail servers are currently down, you may or may not receive a confirmation email');

          print "<h1>You have registered successfully</h1>";
          print "You will receive an email shortly with instructions on how to confirm your email address.</a>";
    }
?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks for any help at resolving this.

Comment: Use prepared statements. Don't build your SQL statements with concatenation. It leaves you open to `SQL INJECTION`.

Comment: could it be as simple as `?email=someone@somewhere.com` not being in the URL? Also, bad way to handle this. you're open to injection attacks. See chris' comment. Switch to mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements

Comment: The OP would get less headaches in using POST instead of GET @KaiQing probably what the problem could be. The GET method is probably playing some nasty tricks.

Comment: @OP --- why 2x of `$query = 'SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = "' . $email . '"';` and `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` ? I don't get it. You only need to use one.

Comment: Change the single quotes to double and vice versa on your query: `$query = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '" . $email . "'";`

Comment: They arent 2 times, one is a "SELECT *" and the other is "SELECT email"

Also, I completely understand that this is open to SQL injections, this is merely a prototype.

I can't use POST, I am sending the GET from android.

Comment: changing single quotes to double and vice versa did not help.

Anything else I should try?

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple answer and I figured it out!

My $ID was being pulled before the record was created, that's why it was blank!  Dumb mistake on my part.